# Swift, How to import JSON file from Pandas JSON file

Tags: python, ios, swift, pandas

I exported JSON file from Pandas,
And I want to import JSON file from Swift/iOS.

The structure of Codable Protocol is correct.

I tried to use SWIFTYJSON, but It also same error happens.

This is the pandas code.

```
shops.to_json("sample.json", orient='records', force_ascii=False, lines=True)
```

I wrote code like this

```
struct Restaurant: Codable {

let url: String
let name: String
let address: String
let pref: String
let zip: String
let tel: String
let latitude: Float
let longitude:Float
let price: String
let category: String
let rate: Float
let moyori: String
let transportation: String
let hours: String
let holiday: String
let website: String

}



guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "json") else { return }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        print(data)
        let restaurant = try JSONDecoder().decode(Restaurant.self, from: data)
        // SWIFTY JSON

        //let json = try JSON(data: data)
        print(restaurant)
    } catch  {
        print(error)
    }
```

The Error is below

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.})))
```

This is the JSON sample

```
{"address":"港区赤坂1-11-6 赤坂テラスハウス １階","category":"割烹・小料理","holiday":"日曜、祝日（詳細は公式HPのカレンダーに記載）","hours":"12:00～15:00(L.O.13:00)(木・土のみ営業)18:00～22:00(L.O.20:00)","latitude":35.6642294444,"longitude":139.7455658333,"moyori":"六本木一丁目","name":"sample restaurant2","pref":"東京都","price":"￥30,000～","rate":"4.88","url":"http://www.sample1.com","tel":"03-0000-0000","transportation":"東京メトロ 銀座線・南北線「溜池山王駅」13出口より、徒歩10分東京メトロ 南北線「六本木一丁目駅」3出口より、徒歩10分東京メトロ 日比谷線「神谷町駅」4b出口より、徒歩10分\n六本木一丁目駅から411m","website":"http://www.sample1.com","zip":"1070052"}
{"address":"港区六本木1-4-5 アークヒルズサウスタワー 1Ｆ","category":"寿司","holiday":"日曜・祝日（但し、連休にならない祝日は除く）","hours":"12:00～14:0017:00～23:00","latitude":35.6621280556,"longitude":139.7426308333,"moyori":"溜池山王","name":"sample restarurant2","pref":"東京都","price":"￥20,000～￥29,999","rate":"4.86","url":"http://www.sample.com","tel":"03-3589-4412","transportation":"溜池山王駅徒歩5分虎ノ門駅徒歩8分\n六本木一丁目駅から60m","website":"","zip":"1060032"}
```

I tested like this jsonfile also

```
   [{"address":"港区赤坂1-11-6 赤坂テラスハウス １階","category":"割烹・小料理","holiday":"日曜、祝日（詳細は公式HPのカレンダーに記載）","hours":"12:00～15:00(L.O.13:00)(木・土のみ営業)18:00～22:00(L.O.20:00)","latitude":35.6642294444,"longitude":139.7455658333,"moyori":"六本木一丁目","name":"sample restaurant2","pref":"東京都","price":"￥30,000～","rate":"4.88","url":"http://www.sample1.com","tel":"03-0000-0000","transportation":"東京メトロ 銀座線・南北線「溜池山王駅」13出口より、徒歩10分東京メトロ 南北線「六本木一丁目駅」3出口より、徒歩10分東京メトロ 日比谷線「神谷町駅」4b出口より、徒歩10分\n六本木一丁目駅から411m","website":"http://www.sample1.com","zip":"1070052"},{"address":"港区六本木1-4-5 アークヒルズサウスタワー 1Ｆ","category":"寿司","holiday":"日曜・祝日（但し、連休にならない祝日は除く）","hours":"12:00～14:0017:00～23:00","latitude":35.6621280556,"longitude":139.7426308333,"moyori":"溜池山王","name":"sample restarurant2","pref":"東京都","price":"￥20,000～￥29,999","rate":"4.86","url":"http://www.sample.com","tel":"03-3589-4412","transportation":"溜池山王駅徒歩5分虎ノ門駅徒歩8分\n六本木一丁目駅から60m","website":"","zip":"1060032"}]
```

errors goes like this

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
enter code here
```

Comment: Your _JSON sample_ is not a valid JSON, as it contains two JSON objects. A valid JSON should be a single JSON array or a single JSON object.

Comment: @OOPer plz check the another jsonfile also,

Comment: Try simplifying your JSON to narrow down what the problems is. Also, do you get the same error with the second example you added?

Comment: not same error so, I posted the Error,

Comment: With your _jsonfile also_, you need to use `[Restaurant].self` instead of `Restaurant.self`.

Comment: I also did that, and If I delete [], it also same error..

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same error with your _jsonfile also_ with `[Restaurant].self`. I said you needed to add`[]`, not _delete []_.

Comment: https://yosuke8080@bitbucket.org/yosuke8080/deliciousfinder.git

Comment: this is the original file, plz check HomeViewController,
I did that thank you

Comment: Your `HomeViewController` has no code using `JSONDecoder`, what do you want to be checked? You mean you could have fixed all the issues by yourself?

Comment: plz check viewdidload

Comment: needJSONDecoder? I just want to import JSON

Comment: You may need to clarify what you are asking. The main part of your question is made of the Swift code using `JSONDecoder` and showing the JSON-like text data with error message output from `JSONDecoder`. And you say _needJSONDecoder?_. Please read your question carefully and clarify what you want to ask.

Comment: sorry for my Poor English, let me check, thank you @OOPer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct Tabelog: Codable {

let url: String
let name: String
let address: String
let pref: String
let zip: String
let tel: String
let latitude: Float
let longitude:Float
let price: String
let category: String
let rate: String
let moyori: String
let transportation: String
let hours: String
let holiday: String
let website: String
```

}

is correct, Type were wrong.
Thank you.